# Laravel postman request returns Unauthenticated

Tags: php, laravel-5, postman

I'm new to laravel and sorry for the silly question I've posted a request via postman with two parameters,In my routes api.php file,

```
Route::post('/mail', 'TripsController@mail');
```

with header,

```
   Accept:application/json
```

And exclude the token verify in VerifyCSRKToken as,

```
protected $except = ['api/*',
      ];
```

and my url:

```
http://localhost/Movecabadmin/api/mail
```

It returns the message as **`{"message":"Unauthenticated."}`**

**Question 1**:Is I need to pass any authentication value with the request?If it is then How?

**Question 2**:How to get the passed parameters in my controller?

Comment: which authentication method are you using?

Comment: do you have passport in your code?

Comment: No I'm not using passport

Comment: Can guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: Is it not possible without authentication?

Comment: could you create one simple function and try to call that? some thing like Route::get('/', function () {
   die(done);
});

Comment: yes it returns perfectly

Comment: How do I pass token with request

Comment: try to define it as post and run it again but add your url to VerifyCsrfToken and try it

Comment: you dont have authentication system yet , but if you have your access_token you can set this to your header => key = Authorization , value = Bearer {your access_token}

Comment: for example I create a web rout like this : Route::post('/test', function () {
    die('test');
}); I have to add this '/test' to VerifyCsrfToken like this :     protected $except = [
        '/test'
    ]; try this

Comment: How to generate access_token

Comment: do you check that examples? you can run for example passport to get your access_token see this url : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: Thanks.Can I use Laravel auth user token for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}` because the `Route::post('/mail', 'TripsController@mail');`
going under some kind of authentication or middleware.

Remove that and you will get your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But then How can  I all controller function?

Comment: Didn't get. You mean how you can add a controller function. What i mean above is that your specified route is going through certain middleware. Something like this `code`Route::group(['prefix' => 'customer', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'customer']], function() {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'Customer\DashboardController@index');
    Route::get('subscriptions', 'Customer\SubscriptionController@index');
}); So take your route outside this block or remove middleware from it.

Comment: _So take your route outside this block or remove middleware from it_.So how do I define the route without going through middleware

Comment: Can  you show the route file content, through that i can explain you better. In routes file take this route `Route::post('/mail', 'TripsController@mail');` outside the group block.